# Sorting Input in Unix Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix, sorting

I am trying to write a Unix Shell Script that when executed it asks the user to enter 4 numbers and the script sort them numerically and print them out.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help,

Andy

Comment: Is the assignment to write a simple sort routine or can you use the `sort` utility? What have you tried so far? Although it's a little late to ask that.

Comment: thank you, yes Dennis i was stuck to this homework and kind of confused but now its fine :-)

Answer (score 4):

Supposing your inputs are in `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, `$d` you can do this

```
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n" $a $b $c $d | sort
```

Comment: You can also write `printf "%s\n" $a $b $c $d ...` -- printf will repeat the format string for excess arguments

Comment: @glenn thanks, I didn't know. I was stuck with the printf function syntax in C :)

Answer (score 3):

another way

```
read -p "Enter 1st number: " a
read -p "Enter 2nd number: " b
read -p "Enter 3rd number: " c
read -p "Enter 4th number: " d
printf "%s\n" $a $b $c $d | sort
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "sort" utility, which reads from stdin and sorts each line lexicographycally.

As an example, you can check:

```
echo -e "1\n6\n2\n3" | sort -n
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
3
6
```

Just output each number on a separate line, and pipe that into sort

Comment: You should have mentioned sort's `-n` option, since question was about **numeric** sort.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the values and then echo them to the sort program.

```
echo -n "Enter 1st number: "
read a junk
echo -n "Enter 2nd number: "
read b junk
echo -n "Enter 3rd number: "
read c junk
echo -n "Enter 4th number: "
read d junk
{ echo $a; echo $b; echo $c; echo $d; } | sort -n
```

The only problem here is the notation used to suppress newlines after the `echo` command.  There are two notations - and different systems use different notations.  The older notation is the `echo -n` shown.  The newer notation is:

```
echo "Enter Nth number: \c"
```

Which you need to use depends on your system, then.

The 'junk' variable collects any extra words after the first word on the input line.  It's a form of paranoia, but means that if the user types '12 abc', then the single-letter variable gets just the '12' and not the rest.  The code does not validate that the user entered a number.  You could write a function to do that, and use it 4 times - it might as well take the prompt string and return a number.

Note that if you use `bash`, the `read` command is much more powerful and can do the prompting as well, side-stepping tricky issues with `echo` notation for non-portable (to other than `bash`) notations in `read` instead.  Except for the `echo` notation, the code shown is portable to Bourne shell back to 7th Edition (or Version 7) UNIX (where `echo` was not a shell built-in and it used the `-n` option) and derivatives (Korn, Bash, POSIX, ...).

Comment: Ok Jonathan, thanks a lot mate. It worked in my system very well :-)